# DIV with overflow-y in Chrome automatically scrolls down to the absolute bottom

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, reflow

To show a lot of records to the user, we use the following approach:

- we have a DIV with overflow-y: scroll. Inside of this DIV we have 3
  DIVs:
- first one and last one are just spacers, so the scrollbar is in
  correct position
- the middle DIV shows the content. Its content is
  loaded dynamically via AJAX from the server based on the position.

It looks like this:

```
<div id="elmain" style="height:400px; width:500px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x:hidden;">
    <div id="eltop" style="height:1500px"></div>
    <div id="elview" style="height:500px;">content</div>
    <div id="elbot" style="height:1500px"></div>
</div>
```

In the onScroll event handler we resize eltop and elbot DIVs, so user can actually see elview. You can try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/hq0r63z8/

Unfortunately, it stopped working in the latest versions of Chrome. It still works in other browsers. Scrolling up works also in Chrome, but when scrolling down, browser scrolls to the absolute bottom.

Do you have any idea, how to fix this?

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No, error log is empty...